# SQL azure database login doesn't work after moving the database to a different server

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

After copying the database from one sql azure server to the other, I am not able to use the same sql accounts for login into the new server database.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the logins on the target server (which has the copy) if not already. The other approach is to use contained user authentication in SQL DB v12. (Contianed users in now supported in SQL DB v12).